Powershell script to enable the cookies in Internet Explorer
We are creating a Windows EC2 instance, installing gateway in pipeline and then registering Microsoft on-premises gateway manually. While registering the gateway, it expects cookies enabled in IE. We are enabling the cookies in IE manually. We want to automate this step and include it in the pipeline. Can someone suggest a powershell script to enable the cookies in IE?
I am currently enabling the cookies as follows:
Select 'Internet Options' from the Tools menu.
Click on the 'Privacy' tab.
Select the 'Advanced' button
Under 'First-party Cookies' and 'Third-party Cookies', choose Accept
Select 'OK' when done


...why do you need IE? The PowerBI Gateway doesn't require IE... and all recent/supported Windows VM images will have Edge available instead.

Thanks Dial for your quick response. We are installing gateway on EC2 instance in AWS. It's not domain joined. when we try to register the gateway, it says 'cookies are blocked'. If I make Edge as a default browser then we are having to click several times in edge browser like 'welcome to Microsoft Edge, Always have access to browsing data...etc.

Try with this:
# Path to Internet Explorer's Privacy settings in the Windows registry
$registryPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3"

# Set the value for '1A10' to controls cookies
# 0 = Allow all cookies, 1 = Block all cookies, 2 = Prompt for cookies

Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name "1A10" -Value 0


@JR Might be worth mentioning you can read all about the internet zones and values here
